# Problems with outputing table from mysql database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm building a site for a seller who wants to be able to have a customer type in a certification number and then recall from a database the information associated with the number. It seems pretty easy and I have the code written. The code works on my local server but when I upload to my remote server I get errors.

An example of what I mean can be found here: https://www.psacard.com

Works on my local server but not on my remote (awardspace).

```
 <table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="10">
<tr>
    <th>Certificate Number</th>
    <th>Player</th>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Sport</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Authenticator</th>
</tr>
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect("server", "user", "password" "database");
$set=$_POST['search'];
if($set) {
$show="SELECT * FROM Certificates where CertificateNum='$set'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $show);
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $rows['CertificateNum'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $rows['Player'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $rows['Item'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $rows['Sport'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $rows['Date'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $rows['Description'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $rows['Authenticator'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<br>";

}
}
else{
echo "Nothing Found";
}
?>
</table>
```

User can type in code to a form and then the info is recalled from a mysql database and displayed in a table.

Error :

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (42000/1044): Access denied for user
>   '2950881_choice'@'%' to database 'Certificates' in
>   /srv/disk3/2950881/www/choiceapproval.dx.am/search_page.php on line 13
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean
>   given    in
>   /srv/disk3/2950881/www/choiceapproval.dx.am/search_page.php on line 17
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in
>   /srv/disk3/2950881/www/choiceapproval.dx.am/search_page.php    on line
>   18

Comment: Please post error.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_connect(): (42000/1044): Access denied for user '2950881_choice'@'%' to database 'Certificates' in /srv/disk3/2950881/www/choiceapproval.dx.am/search_page.php on line 13

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /srv/disk3/2950881/www/choiceapproval.dx.am/search_page.php on line 17

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /srv/disk3/2950881/www/choiceapproval.dx.am/search_page.php on line 18

Comment: That's a pretty clear message. The credentials for the database on your host are not correct. Chances are the credentials you use locally are not the same as those on your hosting provider.

Comment: Check manually to login your databases whit this credentials . If its not correct the problem is your credentials

Comment: Your missing a comma between **"password" "database"**
Should be:
**$conn=mysqli_connect("server", "user", "password", "database");**

Comment: Note that you're open to sql injection

Comment: Your connection string is missing a , between "password" "database" also is your server address correctly set up for outgoing and incoming connections

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. We got it figured out!